# How can I manually activate a new site in a wordpress multisite network?

Tags: multisite, activation, signup

A client signed up for a new site in my multisite network. But, didn't finished the activation because they never received the email to verify and register.

As the network administrator, I don't see a new (pending) site under Sites. I also don't see a new (pending) user under users.

If I go back to the wp-signup.php page for multisites, I get the following error, "That username is currently reserved but may be available in a couple of days."

Somewhere, somehow a new pending user and site is waiting to be activated, but only by an email activation link that's never going to come. How can I manually activate this to continue the registration on a client's behalf?

Comment: If neither of those solutions work for you, go to the wp_signups table as above and just find and delete the entry that failed. You can then reenter the user (without receiving the error message) when the mail problem is fixed and all works again.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress itself has no UI for viewing and managing unactivated users.

You might be interested in the WordPress plugin called [Unconfirmed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/unconfirmed/) that changes this. It adds a new page in the admin that shows a list of unactivated user registrations. For each registration, you have the option of resending the original activation email, or manually activating the user.

Comment: This plugin has been recently updated and looks like it's actively managed. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin mentioned by *swissspidy* does exactly what you want, but it has not been updated for a year, and is not tested with the latest WordPress version. This is why I will also add 2 other solutions here.

**Solution 1**

The **Pending Users** module of my premium plugin **Beyond Multisite** is made to do this. Link to the plugin page: https://codecanyon.net/item/beyond-multisite-utilities-for-wordpress-network-admins/19633352

On the following screenshot you can see the page that the plugin creates and the actions it offers (last column) for each pending user. The plugin has many more features unrelated to what you are asking too.

To activate the signup, simply visit the Pending Users page in the Network Admin Dashboard under Users, and click the **Activate** link in the last column for the row you want.

[image]

**Solution 2**

This solution is a bit more technical, and is good if you rarely need to do this. Also it is free, and there will be no plugin required.

You need to go to the phpMyAdmin panel (usually located in the cPanel of your hosting) and open the database for your multisite (the database name is visible in your wp-config.php file).

Now open the table **wp_signups** (your prefix might be different than wp_) and there find the signup you want to activate. In the column **activation_key** you will see a string. Add this string in the place of XXXXXXXXXXXX in this URL (where example.com is your main site URL) and visit the URL to activate the signup:

```
http://example.com/wp-activate.php?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Basically this is the link that the user receives via email in order to activate the signup.